# Question on Heaviside step functions

Tags: distribution-theory

This is a followup to my existing question:
[Question on Heaviside step function (distribution) identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3353520/147776)

I was trying to show the equality between two Heaviside step functions using their derivatives.

The old question was:

> For $c>0$, and in the sense of distributions:
>
> First:
>
> $$\frac {d}{dt} \theta (ct-z)=c\delta(ct-z)=\frac{1}{c}
>  c\delta(t-\frac{z}{c})=\delta(t-\frac{z}{c})\tag{1}$$
>
> Second:
>
> $$\frac {d}{dt} \theta (t-\frac{z}{c})=\delta(t-\frac{z}{c})\tag{2}$$
>
> So then
>
> $$\theta (ct-z)=\theta (t-\frac{z}{c})\tag{3}$$
>
> to within a constant of integration.
>
> My question was: is that true?
>
> The answer I got was YES.

**MY QUESTION NOW IS:
*Does that mean that $\theta(f(x))$ is identical to $\theta(g(x))$ for any two functions as long as they have identical zeros?  (Assuming the signs of their derivatives are the same at the zeros)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary necessity for $\theta \circ f$ to equal $\theta \circ g$ is $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are negative for the same $x$ and positive for the same $x$ (modulo a null set).

If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable then this will occur if they have the same zeros and the same signs of the derivatives at the zeros. I here require the derivatives to be non-zero. The zero case is possible, but then we have to look at non-zero second derivatives. And so on.

The reason I write "non-zero derivatives" is that for example $\sin(x)^2$ and $-\sin(x)^2$ have the same zeros and the same derivatives at the zeros, but they have not the same sign: $\theta(\sin(x)^2)$ is a "square wave" while $\theta(-\sin(x)^2)$ vanishes.

Comment: I think only the signs of the derivatives need be the same--not the derivatives themselves.  Your criterion is too restrictive.

Comment: @user45664. Are you referring to "and the same non-zero derivatives at the zeros"? If so, I agree. It should read something like "and the same signs of the non-zero derivatives at the zeros". This is still too restrictive; it excludes functions with zero derivatives at the zeros.

Comment: Please see my next question on this subject:https: //math.stackexchange.com/q/3417092/147776

Comment: update your answer here and i will accept it

Comment: @user45664. Done.