# Another Heaviside step function question

Tags: distribution-theory

I previously asked the question:

[Question on Heaviside step functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3414324/147776)

> Is $θ(f(x))$ is identical to $θ(g(x))$ for any two
>   functions as long as they have identical zeros? (Assuming the signs of
>   their derivatives are the same at the zeros)

If the answer is yes then their derivatives should be the same, ie.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\theta(f(x))=  \frac{d}{dx}\theta(g(x))$$

which means that

$$\theta_x(f(x))f_x(x)=  \theta_x(g(x))g_x(x)$$

or

$$\delta(f(x))f_x(x)=  \delta(g(x))g_x(x)$$

MY QUESTION IS: *is this correct?*

Comment: First we need to make sure that the derivatives are defined, if not as ordinary derivatives then at least as distributional derivatives.

Comment: Question (mostly to myself): Is the chain rule valid here?

Comment: Everything is in the sense of distributions, and i think the chain rule must be valid--no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not obvious that the chain rule is valid for distributions. But in this case it actually is.

Assume that $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ changes sign at $x_i$ for $i \in I$ (finite or countably infinite). Then 
$$
(\theta \circ f)'(x) 
= \sum_{i \in I} \operatorname{sign}(f'(x_i)) \, \delta(x-x_i)
.
$$

On the other hand, formally by the chain rule, in a neighborhood of $x_0$ we expect to have
$$
(\theta \circ f)'(x) 
= (\theta' \circ f)(x) \, f'(x)
= (\delta \circ f)(x) \, f'(x)
.
$$

Are these right hand sides equal? Actually they are. By a formula that can be found in [Dirac Delta Function of a Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276583/168433) we have
$$
(\delta \circ f)(x) \, f'(x) 
= \left( \sum_{i \in I} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|} \right) \, f'(x)
= \sum_{i \in I} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|} \, f'(x_i) \\
= \sum_{i \in I} \frac{f'(x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|} \,\delta(x-x_i)
= \sum_{i \in I} \operatorname{sign}(f'(x_i)) \,\delta(x-x_i)
.
$$

Thus, to answer your question: Yes, it is correct that $\delta(f(x)) \, f'(x) =  \delta(g(x)) \, g'(x)$ if $f,g \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\theta \circ f = \theta \circ g$ (e.g. if $f$ and $g$ have the same zeros, and $f'$ and $g'$ have the same (nonzero) signs at the zeros).